# I want to know how to add names to the edges? I'm new with Dijkstra algorithm

Tags: c++, dijkstra

I'm suppose to to give the shortest path from one place to another. I'm totally new with this, so I'm starting small. Just like 10 intersections around my place. However, I got how to print out the path from one place to another. I'm trying to figure out how to assign the names to this edges. And I don't know if using adjacency matrix is the best option. What if I have more than 100 nodes? How can I do it?

```
// A C++ program for Dijkstra's single source shortest path algorithm. 
// The program is for adjacency matrix representation of the graph 
#include <iostream>
#include <limits.h> 
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

// Number of vertices in the graph 
#define V 14

// A utility function to find the vertex with minimum distance value, from 
// the set of vertices not yet included in shortest path tree 
int minDistance(int dist[], bool sptSet[])
{
    // Initialize min value 
    int min = INT_MAX, min_index;

    for (int v = 0; v < V; v++)
        if (sptSet[v] == false && dist[v] <= min)
            min = dist[v], min_index = v;

    return min_index;
}

void printPath(int parent[], int j)
{

    // Base Case : If j is source 
    if (parent[j] == -1)
        return;

    printPath(parent, parent[j]);

    cout << " --> " << j;
}



// A utility function to print the constructed distance array 
void printSolution(int dist[], int n, int parent[])
{
    printPath(parent, n);
    cout << "\nThe distance from Source to Destination is: "<< dist[n] << endl;
}

// Function that implements Dijkstra's single source shortest path algorithm 
// for a graph represented using adjacency matrix representation 
void dijkstra(int graph[V][V], int src, int destination)
{
    int dist[V];     // The output array.  dist[i] will hold the shortest distance from src to i 

    bool sptSet[V]; // sptSet[i] will be true if vertex i is included in shortest path tree or shortest distance from src to i is finalized 

    int parent[V];      // Parent array to store shortest path tree

    // Initialize all distances as INFINITE and stpSet[] as false 
    for (int i = 0; i < V; i++) {
        dist[i] = INT_MAX;
        sptSet[i] = false;
        parent[i] = -1;
    }

    // Distance of source vertex from itself is always 0 
    dist[src] = 0;

    // Find shortest path for all vertices 
    for (int count = 0; count < V - 1; count++)
    {
        // Pick the minimum distance vertex from the set of vertices not 
        // yet processed. u is always equal to src in the first iteration. 
        int u = minDistance(dist, sptSet);
        if (u == destination)
            break;
        // Mark the picked vertex as processed 
        sptSet[u] = true;

        // Update dist value of the adjacent vertices of the picked vertex. 
        for (int v = 0; v < V; v++)

            // Update dist[v] only if is not in sptSet, there is an edge from  
            // u to v, and total weight of path from src to  v through u is  
            // smaller than current value of dist[v] 

            if (!sptSet[v] && graph[u][v] && dist[u] != INT_MAX && dist[u] + graph[u][v] < dist[v]) {
                parent[v] = u;
                dist[v] = dist[u] + graph[u][v];
            }
    }

    // print the constructed distance array 
    cout << "From " << src;
    printSolution(dist, destination, parent);
}

// driver program to test above function 
int main()
{
    /* Let us create the example graph discussed above */
    int graph[V][V] = { {0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
                    {5, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
                {0, 6, 0, 3, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
                {0, 0, 3, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
                {0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7},
                {0, 0, 7, 0, 4, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0},
                {0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0},
                {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 3, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0},
                {8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0},
                {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0},
                {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 3, 0, 4, 0, 0},
                {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 4, 0},
                {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 4},
                {0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0}
    };

    dijkstra(graph, 0, 13);


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: An adjacency matrix doesn't lend itself well to the addition of  human-readable names, but `std::string names[V];` would provide a good look-up table.